# Determine the storage order of an Eigen3 matrix at compile time

Tags: c++, c++11, eigen3

The title basically says everything. Is there some member of Eigen::Matrix that exposes the storage order (column major or row major) at compile time? I know that the `Options` template parameter is used for specifying the storage order but I have not found a way to extract it afterwards. The usage scenario would be something like

```
template<class Mat>
class C {
  static_assert(/* Mat has column major format */, "column major required");
  // ...
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Mat::IsRowMajor`:

```
static_assert(!Mat::IsRowMajor, "column major required");
```

This will work for any Eigen's matrix-like type for `Mat`, like `Matrix`, `Block`, `Map`, `Ref`, etc.